# How to use PDFsharp to display my local PDF file in WPF application?

Tags: pdfsharp

How to use PDFsharp to display my local PDF file in WPF application?

I want to know how to display and search in a window by PDFsharp.

I just want to open my local PDF file, and just display and search something in this PDF on the WPF window by using PDFsharp.

Please tell me the code how to use it.

Comment: Add your code. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAQs are overrated.
https://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Can_PDFsharp_show_PDF_files_Print_PDF_files_Create_images_from_PDF_files_3

PDFsharp cannot render PDF files and it cannot show PDF files.

Comment: oh, thank you for replying. Can pdfsharp search text in local pdf file? And highline the text?

Comment: @LiangJiechao You can use PDFsharp to search text in a PDF file, but highlighting that text will be difficult.